# Django: How to access model fields via a OneToOne relationship in views.py?

Tags: python, django

in models.py i have tow models:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user   = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images/account/avatar', default='/static/images/default-avatar.png')
    bio    = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)

class Author(models.Model):
    user = OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

in views.py in want to access username (it is in User model)
the code in views.py:

```py
def author(request, username):
    authors = ...

    context = {
        'authors': authors
    }

    return render(request, 'account/profile.html', context)
```

what should be placed instead of three points in front of the `authors=`?
for example `authors = Author.user.user.get(username=username)` but it don't work.

Comment: what should `authors` contain? The `Author` objects with a profile with a related `User` where the `username` matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the `Author` object which has a related `Profile` which has a related `User` with the given username with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def author(request, username):
    author = get_object_or_404(Author, user__user__username=username)

    context = {
        'author': author
    }
    return render(request, 'account/profile.html', context)
```

Since the `username`s are unique, and you use `OneToOneField`s, there is *at most* one such `Author`. We thus fetch this as `author`, and in the context it is better to work with `author`, not <s>`authors`</s>.

Furthermore you might want to rename the `OneToOneField` from the `Author` model: since it refers to a `Profile` and not a `User`, `profile` is more appropriate:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    profile = OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If the field is renamed, the view should be modified to:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def author(request, username):
    author = get_object_or_404(Author, profile__user__username=username)

    context = {
        'author': author
    }
    return render(request, 'account/profile.html', context)
```

Comment: it don't work. This error is shown: Cannot resolve keyword 'profile' into field

Comment: @Ahmad: it is `user__user__username`, not `profile__user__username`.